# How to scale wcf server?

Tags: c#, wcf

Wcf-client sends a remote query, wcf can run all incoming queriea parallel on a single machine. But, for example, there's another machine with the same wcf server ready to process incoming queries as well. How can I put in place that another machine?

Comment: [Load balancing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're talking about horizontal scaling (distribute the load across multiple servers), so the best option is use load balancing.

Of course, to reach this, you must have available any load balance resource, hardware (like a CISCO) or software (a NLB for instance).

Anyway, you must consider that some bindings has particular issues that may impact in load balancing, for instance session affinity, due to IP restrictions or HTTP Keep-Alive enabled.

You can read more about things to consider using load balancing here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh273122(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, read about load balancing on the link that @Joachim commented:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx